# 'Set Warranty Bit: Recovery' Samsung doesn't boot

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, unbricking, samsung-galaxy-j5, lucky-patcher

I have a Samsung Galaxy J5 and it isn't booting since I patched an app with Lucky Patcher (first time I tried it). I have had the root for some time, with no problems, but now I boot it and it goes black after showing the logo and 'Set Warranty Bit: recovery' for a second.

I have a backup with Titanium Backup in my PC, and would like to know if I should **flash a custom ROM** I found for my device or **flash a stock version** (custom ROM works for everyone and comes with instructions, but I don't trust so much the stock version). Also, the custom ROM has a lot of steps, but there is no cyanogenmod version for the J5.

Thanks in advance! (also, is there any other solution?)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this guide](https://rootmygalaxy.net/unroot-unbrick-samsung-galaxy-j5/). It is designed specifically for the Galaxy J5 and all flashing software **and** the ROM are obtained from official Samsung sources. Outline:

1. Backup your data
2. Install Samsung USB drivers (No link because it will probably die soon, Google is your friend)
3. Install ADB & Fastboot drivers if you haven't already. ([HowToGeek](https://www.howtogeek.com/125769/how-to-install-and-use-abd-the-android-debug-bridge-utility/))
4. Enable USB debugging (if you can)

Make sure your phone is charged. If you can't see any indicators of battery life leave it on the charger for 2 hours.

5. Download and install Odin ([download here](https://odindownload.com/download/))
6. Download the stock ROM for your phone ([here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180419131505/http://samsung-updates.com/device/?id=SM-J500F))
7. Turn off your Galaxy J5 and Boot in download mode: Hold down Volume Down + Home + Power button at the same time
8. Connect it to the PC with USB cable and run Odin.
9. If everything is right and drivers are working properly. You will see the blue box on the Odin screen, if not reinstall the drivers again and reboot your PC.
10. Now select the AP option from the Odin screen and select the firmware file that you extracted.
11. Hit the Start button from the Odin screen to start the flashing process.

Once completed you will see the PASS messages on the Odin and the phone will reboot automatically. Now you can disconnect your phone.

IMPORTANT: If your phone is stuck in the boot loop or in the Samsung Android Logo then turn off the phone and reboot into recovery mode. To do this, hold down the Volume Up + Home + Power buttons at the same time. Now from recovery, select Wipe Data/Factory Reset and after that Wipe cache partition. Now reboot you phone.